# How do i send request to server with post method when using a HTML menu

Tags: html, post, menu

there is a menu with 5 select key in my HTML program . By clicking each of these keys a request should send to server . I use 'a' tag and href for this . by this approach i have to send request with GET method but i want use POST . For sending request by POST , I use 'form' tag for each of these keys . so for 5 key i use 5 'form' tag .  Is this a common and acceptable way? haven't i any better way for sending request with POST? thanks

```
            <form action="{{url('/defineProject')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}          
                    <input id="a1" class="s1" type="submit" value="define project">                                      
         </form>
        <form action="{{url('/deleteProject')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}          
                    <input id="a2" class="s1" type="submit" value="delete project ">                                         
         </form>
        <form action="{{url('/upgradeProject')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}          
                    <input id="a3" class="s1" type="submit" value="upgrade project ">                                        
         </form>
        <form action="{{url('/reportProject')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}          
                    <input id="a4" class="s1" type="submit" value="report Project">                                      
         </form> 
        <form action="{{url('/editProject')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}          
                    <input id="a5" class="s1" type="submit" value="edit project">                                        
         </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="YOUR_BACKEND_URL_ENDPOINT">
    <select name="YOUR_FIELD_NAME">
        <option value="VALUE_1"> VALUE_1_NAME </option>
        <option value="VALUE_2"> VALUE_2_NAME </option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

I guess this should work.

Comment: thanks . where should i use type="submit" for send request in this code?

Comment: I think you're probably talking about a button inside the form, I've updated my answer to have a submit button

Comment: thanks again but each of options should has its own submit . it means  when user select an option the form should send related request

Comment: you can use onChange on the form tag and call a js function for this

Answer (score -1):

maybe this is the answer you looking for?
`<form method="POST"></form>`

Comment: Add your code to get better answer from the audience